How to make .py file executable (OSX)
I am  new to Python and still trying to get past something more practical than  copy&paste (and I do search for answers and try everything suggested before posting a question)... I have tried Laincher, VSC, Jupyter, and all either have problems each  is different) or the graph plot when displayed loses the tool bar.  Copy script ( RGB_plot.py ) and paste into a Python shell in terminal and works quickly and without issues.
I am trying make it executable so I can convert to  .app and run from a desktop icon (and uultimately in the background... but one thing at a time)
After looking at a number of answers  about making executable, I have inserted the following at the first lines:
#!/usr/bin/env python

from os import chmod

chmod +x RGB_plot.py

Initially it was only the top and bottom line. bottom line started with  $ which resulted in  "\u24" error,
I added the  middle line  "from os import chmod" which eliminated "chmod not defined Pylance.... but I get the same not defined for 'x' and RGB_plot.py (perhaps because it is also the name of the script???)
Here's the script
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})


df = pd.read_excel('/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB     plots.xlsx')
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(left=0)
(0.0, 1.0)
ax.set_ylim(0.0, 1.0)

ax.set_zlim(bottom=0)
(0.0, 1.0)

for i in range(len(df)):
ax.scatter3D(df['R'][i], df['G'][i], df['B'][i], 
             marker=df['M'][i], c=df['C'][i], alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')

plt.show()


try running chmod +x RGB_plot.py from your shell not from within the python script. You likely also don't need the import then.

Save your Python script on your Desktop as RGB_plot.py.
Now start Terminal and change the mode of your script to be executable by running:
chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/RGB_plot.py

You only need to do that once.
Now you can execute, i.e. run your script by typing the following into Terminal:
$HOME/Desktop/RGB_plot.py


If you are already in your HOME directory, you can just use:
Desktop/RGB_plot.py


If it still doesn't work, check that you have saved your script properly and not as RTF by running the following in Terminal:
file $HOME/Desktop/RGB_plot.py

and add the output to your question, along with the full Python script.

I get the following                                                                                                (base) stanbrown@iMac-2 ~ % $HOME/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: line 1: import: command not found
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: line 2: import: command not found
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: line 3: import: command not found
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: line 4: import: command not found
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: line 5: import: command not found
/Users/stanbrown/De....

and this                                                                                                                     (base) stanbrown@iMac-2 ~ % file $HOME/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py
/Users/stanbrown/Desktop/Plot/RGB_plot.py: ASCII text

Your Mac says that because it doesn't know the script needs to be run within Python. Add the following as the first line of your script #!/usr/bin/env python and try #!/usr/bin/env python3 if that fails.

python3 works- takes it a bit of time,but  it works!  Thank you so much- Ive spent the better part of 2 days with this!

You may be able to double-click on the Python file now too - I can't remember.
